# Security extension for Magento, scanning server for changes files

Tags: security, magento

I use a plugin for WordPress called "WordFence". It works by scanning all files on the server and checking for changes or suspicious code.

I am looking for something similar to Magento. Does it exist?

To put it another way, I am looking for an extension to help with security, and scanning files looking for changes would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a version control system for that, as it does exactly what you describe (and more).

For example, `git status` will show you all modified files since last release. You could use `.gitignore` to exclude media files and other volatile stuff.

See [Yireo's tutorial on git and Magento](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/1741-git-best-practices-for-magento) on how to get started.

Comment: That's a good start but such an extension should do more, like find malicious code hidden in `media`, which is not unusual

Comment: @fschmengler how would you go about that? grep for `<?` in media files?

Comment: Probably yes, or search for *.php files but that might not be enough.

Comment: So an extension like this doesn't exist? This is the one we're using for WordPress. https://www.wordfence.com/